# request_irq fails because there is no irq descriptor

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt

I have a Linux system which I'm connecting to custom hardware. (To be specific, this is an SoC with an FPGA).

I am trying to write a kernel module that will respond to interrupts from my device. It contains a call to `request_irq`, but this is done via a call to `uio_register_device`. When I run `insmod`, it fails with "Invalid parameters".

After poking around the code for a while, I eventually added these lines in my module init function:

```
struct irq_desc *p;
p = irq_to_desc(89);
if (!p) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "No descriptor allocated for IRQ number 89!!\n");
}
p = irq_to_desc(121);
if (!p) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "No descriptor allocated for IRQ number 121!!\n");
}
```

Sure enough, I see these messages in `dmesg`.

What am I supposed to do in this case?

Comment: Your resource provider (ACPI or DT) should properly describe IRQ resources. Note, in modern systems the amount of IRQ chips usually great than one. Plain numbers are ambiguous.

Comment: Is there some way for me to add the interrupt descriptor myself? It seems like the resource provider is not doing it

Comment: First, you need to figure out what the system is based on: ACPI or DT or something else. In ACPI or DT cases it is possible (in many cases) to extend / override the settings.

Comment: Hi @0andriy, I managed to cobble together a solution. Could you look at my answer and make sure it's ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. For interrupts to work properly, you need to *map* a virtual IRQ number (i.e. the number you would use in `request_interrupt`) to a hardware IRQ number. Of course, hardware IRQ numbers are not unique; for example, two interrupt controllers could have a hardware IRQ number of 0. So what I really mean is that you have to associate the virtual IRQ number with the *combination* of an `irq_domain` and a hardware IRQ number.

There's a little more to it than that: `irq_domain`s do not correspond 1-to-1 with interrupt controllers. A single controller could have more than one domain.

So, let's precisely define what we mean by "mapping" IRQs:

1. Each virtual IRQ has a `struct irq_desc`. Some of this struct's fields are mapped to point to the functions implemented by the interrupt controller driver. (I'm not sure what Linux does when it receives an interrupt before you do any mapping)
2. Each interrupt controller can provide some number of `struct irq_domain`s. These essentially encode the mapping between hardware IRQ numbers to virtual IRQ numbers, and have an API for drivers to look up numbers.
3. The `irq_domain` struct also contains pointers to callbacks which are implemented by the interrupt controller driver. One of these callbacks is triggered when you create a new mapping; I think this is how the hardware is configured to generate particular virtual IRQs.

When you request an interrupt, your ISR will be added to the `actions` list in the `irq_desc`, provided the `irq_desc` has been properly initialized.

Anyway the method I found for getting the virtual IRQ number given a hardware IRQ number (and creating a new mapping if necessary) is as follows:

```
#include <linux/irqdomain.h> //For irq_domain struct
#include <linux/of.h> //For device tree struct types
#include <linux/irq.h> //Needed by other interrupt-related code

struct device_node *dn;
struct irq_domain *dom;
struct irq_fwspec dummy_fwspec = {
    .param_count = 3,
    .param = {0, 89, 4}
};
int virq;

//Find the Linux irq number
dn = of_find_node_by_name(NULL, "interrupt-controller");
if (!dn) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Could not find device node for \"interrupt-controller\"\n");
    goto /*error_handler*/;
}
dom = irq_find_host(dn);
if (!dom) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Could not find irq domain\n");
    goto /*error_handler*/;
}

dummy_fwspec.fwnode = dom->fwnode;
virq = irq_create_fwspec_mapping(&dummy_fwspec);
```

The `irq_create_fwspec_mapping` will either return an existing (mapped) virtual IRQ number, or map a new one. The `struct irq_fwspec` contains all the information that would be needed to perform the mapping. The `fwnode` field must point to the interrupt controller you are using; in my case, I found the correct value using the device tree API (there might be a better way, but I don't know what it is!)

This example is specifically for an MPSoC, and I happen to know it uses [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c) driver (drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c). I looked at the driver's source code to figure out what it wanted in the other parts of the `irq_fwspec` struct. Specifically, each controller driver will fill a `struct irq_domain_ops`, so CTRL-F for that to find the callback functions you need to satisfy.

In my specific example, I knew the `gic_irq_domain_alloc` would be called, and that it would also call `gic_irq_domain_translate`. This told me that the 2nd number was the hardware IRQ number, but that for some reason 32 would be added to it. Since I wanted hardware IRQ number 121, I plugged in 89 for the 2nd number. The first and third numbers are kind of a guess based on what I've seen other people doing.

If someone knows a simpler way to do this, let me know

Comment: It should be simple done in DTS (if your platform uses Device Tree) or in ACPI (this would be an interesting task, though I think GIC provides interrupt resources in a similar way as IOAPIC on x86). But it’s good you dived into this deeply than needed.

Comment: GIC devices usually follow this format: the first cell is the interrupt type (0: for SPI, 1: for PPI); the second cell is the hardware (irq - 32) eg hwirq 34 becomes "2"; and the third cell is the interrupt flag (1:rising, 2:falling, 4:high, 8:low)